# Регулярка - выбрать по шаблону с конца строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не получается составить шаблон для последней части строки.

```
$string = '201706151400_NEW_SIL_db-n8-stanc_DBCollectorConf_HUB_SQL_ST_MSI_VIEW_TEST_dima.gz';

$newstring = preg_replace('/(NEW_|_DBCollectorConf|\.gz)/', '',$string);
```

Как не пробовал - не могу подобрать шаблон, чтобы попадала еще только последняя часть строки: "_dima". 
В ней может содержаться цифры или буквы любой длины.

Comment: видимо дописать этого диму к .gz: `_.*?\.gz`

Comment: Тогда попадает под шаблон вся строка. кроме даты https://regex101.com/r/Ahjllj/2

Comment: тогда так https://regex101.com/r/nHLPWo/1

Comment: Точно, работает.

Comment: Попробуйте `/(NEW_|_DBCollectorConf|\.gz)$/`

Comment: @DimaKuzmin: А `.gz` без `_dima` нужно удалить? Тогда нужно использовать [`NEW_|_IUMCollectorConf|(?:_[^_]+)?\.gz`](https://regex101.com/r/aFLj1f/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В изначальном варианте `'/(NEW_|_DBCollectorConf|\.gz)/` находит следующие подстроки

- `NEW_` - подстрока `NEW_`
- `_DBCollectorConf` - подстрока  `_DBCollectorConf`
- `\.gz` - подстрока  `.gz`.

Если нужно оставить всё как есть, и разрешить опциональное совпадение `_` + 1 и более символов, отличных от `_` перед `.gz`, нужно использовать

```
'~NEW_|_IUMCollectorConf|(?:_[^_]+)?\.gz~'
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/aFLj1f/2).

`(?:_[^_]+)?` является незахватывающей группой (`(?:...)?`, не создаёт буфера в памяти для части совпадения), которая находит 1 или 0 совпадений  `_`, после которого следует 1 и более символов, отличных от `_` (`[^_]+`).